# Print everything after a few specific characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

My intention was use the index method to search for either a colon (:) or a equal sign (=)  in the string and print everything after that character but I realized it's not syntactically possible as it's written below with the OR statement. So is there another way to write this piece of code? (I wasn't able to come up with a simple way to write this without getting into loops and if statements)

```
l='Name = stack'
pos=l.index(':' or '=')  
print (' '.join(l[pos+1:-1].split())) #this just gets rid of the whitespaces
```

Comment: `ind = l.index(":"); if ind == -1: ind = l.index("="); print(l[pos+1:])` or, terribly, `print(l[max([l.index(":"), l.index("=")])+1:])`, though that's practically unreadable. Point being - you need to break up the `.index()` into two separate tests

Comment: `':' or '='` evaluates to `':'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your example as above, the long way (explanation of each piece below):

```
pos = max(l.find(':'), l.find('='), 0)      
print(l[pos:].strip())
```

Here's a way to shorten it to one line, with an explanation of each part in the order it's evaluated in.

```
print(l[max(l.find(':'),l.find('='),0):].strip())
#--------------- Breakdown
# max -> highest of values; find returns -1 if it isn't there.
#        using a 0 at the end means if ':'/'=' aren't in the string, print the whole thing.
# l.find(),l.find() -> check the two characters, using the higher due to max()
# l[max():] -> use that higher value until the end (implied with empty :])
# .strip() -> remove whitespace
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! Just a fyi, find returns -1 if the string isn't there and index raises an exception.

Comment: Yeah, no problem; thanks for the catch- answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

l='Name = stack'
print(re.split(':|=', l)[-1])
```

Regular expression split on either character, then take the last result.

You didn't mention if there was guaranteed to be one or the other separator and not both, always a separator, not more than one separator... this might not do what you want, depending.

Answer (score 1):

You should limit the number of splits to one, using `maxsplit` in `re.split()`:

```
import re

s1 = 'name1 = x1 and noise:noise=noise'
s2 = 'name2: x2 and noise:noise=noise'
print(re.split(':|=', s1, maxsplit=1)[-1].strip())
print(re.split(':|=', s2, maxsplit=1)[-1].strip())
```

Output:

```
x1 and noise:noise=noise
x2 and noise:noise=noise
```